# How do you stop injection in this PHP/PDO

Tags: php, pdo

So I have look at so many post, web sites and video and now I am so confused!  I can't seem to get it right.
How do you stop injection in this PHP/PDO.  I have this code that works, but it allows injection.

```
//*THIS WORKS BUT ALLOWS INJECTION
//*

//The variable $word comes from another php file where the search is created.
public function getAllCards($word) {

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB='".$word."'";

foreach ($this->conn->query($sql) as $row) {

    echo json_encode($row)."<br>"."<br>";
}

$db = null;
}
```

With this new code I am trying to remove the variable  "$word"  from the   "SELECT * FROM "  statement 
to stop the injection and add the  "prepare"   and the  error checking and the   "execute" statement,  but I can't get it right. How would I do this?     FYI this is a GoDaddy shared server.

```
//Getting the search "word" from the GetCards.php
 public function getAllCards($word) {

    //Empty var to store all returned info from db
    $returnArray = array();


    // sql statement to be executed 
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB=':word";

    // prepare to be executed 
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare($sql);


    // error occurred
    if (!$statement) {
        throw new Exception($statement->error);
    }


    // execute statement
    $statement->execute( :word => '$word' );


//run the query
foreach ($this->conn->query($statement) as $row) {

echo json_encode($row)."<br>"."<br>";

}

    // store all appended $rows in $returnArray to be sent to app
    $returnArray[] = $row;   
}
```

Comment: if you run your code, you should see an error. Read the correct syntax [in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've almost got it. PDO, like many database drivers, will be responsible for all of the escaping, so just leave the placeholder as plain as possible:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB=:word";
```

No `'` necessary there.

Now when you `execute()` a PDO statement you get a result which you need to capture into a variable:

```
$res = $statement->execute([ 'word' => $word ]);
```

As Ibu and chris85 point out the `'$word'` part is also incorrect. Avoid quoting single variables, it's not only pointless, it can cause trouble, like here where you're binding to literally *dollar-sign word*, not the value in question. This goes doubly for `"$word"`.

Then you fetch from that. Right now you're calling `query()` on the statement, which is incorrect.

Another thing to note is kicking the habit of making throw-away variables like `$sql` as these are just junk. Instead pass the argument directly:

```
$statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB=:word");
```

This avoids accidentally mixing up `$sql3` with `$sql8` if you're juggling a bunch of these things.

Comment: note that his execute method was incorrect, maybe expanding rather then `$statement->execute(...)` would be useful here

Comment: @Ibu Added a note, thanks! Lots of little mistakes in the original code, but I think it's good that people are trying to do it the right way.

Comment: @chris85 Using the new array notation here should fix that. Another good catch.

Comment: After reworking this there is still an errors at line 156 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' in /xxxxxxxx/DbOperation.php:156 Stack trace: #0 /xxxxxxxx/GetCards.php(39): DbOperation->getAllCards(NULL) #1 {main} thrown in /xxxxxxxxxx/DbOperation.php on line 156
Line 156 is the 
   // error occurred
        if (!$statement) {
            throw new Exception($statement->error);            
        }
and line 39 is in GetCards.php which is  $card->getAllCards($word);
156 is the throw new Exception statement.

Comment: Is this telling me that on this line of code 
 $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB=:word");
that the   businessNameDB=:word)   is NULL.  This makes sense.
If I rem out line 156 ( this is the throw new Exception statement.) 
I get   Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /xxxxxxx/DbOperation.php on line 162

Comment: Line 162 is the  // execute statement
 $res = $statement->execute([ 'word' => $word ]);
1:  I may be wrong but is it telling me that "word"  in businessNameDB=:word)   is NULL.  This makes sense.
2:  So how can I run the error occurred statement if   businessNameDB=:word)   is NULL
3:  How can I run the    // execute statement
        $res = $statement->execute([ 'word' => $word ]); 
if word is NULL?

Comment: If you're getting "on boolean" errors that means your query failed, so find out where something went wrong earlier in your code by testing results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148461/discussion-between-dscrown-and-tadman).

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i have now.

```
  //Getting the search "word" from the GetCards.php
 public function getAllCards($word) {

    //Empty var to store all returned info from db
    $returnArray = array();


    //  prepare to be executed sql statement to be executed if not entered word
    $statement = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB=:word");



    // error occurred
//        if (!$statement) {
//           throw new Exception($statement->error);

//        }


    // execute statement
    $res = $statement->execute([ 'word' => $word ]);


//run the query
foreach ($this->conn->query($res) as $row) {

echo json_encode($row)."<br>"."<br>";

}

    // store all appended $rows in $returnArray to be sent to app
    $returnArray[] = $row;   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this working

```
//*FUNCTION TO GET CARD FROM SEARCH WORD CALLED FROM GetCards.php   
public function getAllCards($word) {

//Connect to db using the PDO not PHP
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx', 'xxxx', 'xxxx');

//Here we prepare the SELECT statement from the search word place holder :word
$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM carddbtable WHERE businessNameDB=:word');

//We execute the $sql with the search word variable"$word"
$sql->execute([':word' => $word]);

//Looping through the results
foreach ($sql as $row)

//Print to screen
echo json_encode($row). "<br>"."<br>";
}
```